# Master Balls att Poké Marts?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is it true that you can unlock Mater Balls at the Poké Marts and how if possible? If not, where can I find more Master Balls?

Answer (score 2):

> **No, you cannot unlock Master Balls to purchase at a Poké Mart.**

The only possible ways are to do:

> **1.** After defeating Valerie in Laverre City, your friends will tell you to meet up near the Poké Ball Factory, at the northern part of the city. After beating Team Flare in the factory, the president of the factory will give you a Master Ball. The Master Ball is obtained in the storyline. You can only obtain the Master Ball once per game in this method.
>
> **2.**  Another way to get a Master Ball is the Lottery Corner found in Lumiose City on Estival Avenue. 
>   The lottery at Lumiose City is the LOTO-ID Center. Matching all five numbers rewards you with a Master Ball.
>
> **3.**  Finally, you can get a Master Ball in a trade as a Pokémon's held item.

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134314/where-can-i-get-a-master-ball)